# Vowel ending detection via regex

Tags: java, regex

With regular expressions, how can I test just the *last* characters of the given string for a match?

I want to check if something *ends* in any of the following:

```
vowel+consonant ("like 'ur' in devour")
vowel+'nt' ("paint")
vowel+'y' ("play")
```

and some others that are similar.

How can I do this with regular expressions (in Java)?

---

edit:
How would I use regular expressions to find out if a verb ends in the pattern

```
consonant-'e'
```

or various other combinations like

```
'ss' 'x' 'sh' 'ch' (sibilants)
```

in order to properly conjugate them in English as verbs.

Comment: Essentially you're talking about all words, except the ones that have no vowels, such as _fly_ and _rhythm_.  Then it would be just checking if there's a vowel in the word or not, no?

Comment: what about see and sea? and be and bee?

Comment: What about accented characters like `à` or `ü`?

Comment: @BeemerGuy:  I am checking (only) verbs with these expressions in order to properly conjugate them.  Perhaps I chose a bad example set.

Comment: @sova: Are you attempting to figure out which English verbs take `-es` in the 3rd-person singular vs those that take only `-s`? That’s what it looks like you are doing.  Those are the same as which nouns take `-es` for their regular plurals.  There is a pattern for that.  Gimme a sec to find it.  It’s in the source code for the superlatively complete [Perl Lingua::EN::Inflect](http://search.cpan.org/~dconway/Lingua-EN-Inflect-1.893/lib/Lingua/EN/Inflect.pm) module.

Comment: @sova: Well, you aren’t going to be able to do this neatly in a single pattern.  But `perl -MLingua::EN::Inflect=PL -le 'print "noun plural of $_ is ", PL($_) for @ARGV' fix lose toss rush catch child ox march monkey curry` does correctly pull out *fixes, loses, tosses, rushes, catches, children, oxen, marches, monkeys,* and  *curries*.

Comment: @BeemerGuy: *fly* and *rhythm* certainly have vowels in them! The first has one syllable whose vowel is *y*, here pronounced `/aɪ/`. The second has two syllables, with *y* pronounced `/ɪ/` in the first and *m* pronounced `/m/` or if you prefer `/əm/` in the second (I don’t prefer: nasals and lenguals can be syllabic centers). For *rhythm* the OED gives `/ˈrɪð(ə)m/`. Their verb-singular inflections are the same as their noun-plural inflections: *flies, rhythms*.

Comment: @hhafez: *annoy bathe buoy coccyx crescendo dye gypsy house lazy monkey myrrhy playa pony sea see spy survey syzygy tarry yes yoyo zero* => *annoys bathes buoys coccyxes crescendos dyes gypsies houses lazies monkeys myrrhies playas ponies seas sees spies surveys syzygies tarries yeses yoyos zeroes*. But *mouse* => *mice* as a noun, but *mouse* => *mouses* as a verb.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the expression that you want. The first bit checks for the vowel and the second looks for any consonant or 'nt'

`[aeiou]([^aeiou\W\d]|nt)$`

I've checked it on http://regexpal.com/ which is my usual tester. The `[^aeiou\W\d]` means 'any that isn't a vowel, is alpha-numeric but isn't a number'. It could just be replace by all the consonants, I suppose:

`[aeiou]([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]|nt)$`

Note that this ignores any possibility of any characters other than those listed. It also tests lower case but I'm unsure how to do case insensitive regex in Java.

Comment: +1 For the second approach which was almost identical to [what I was cooking up](http://regexpal.com/?flags=m&regex=\[aeiou\]%28nt|\[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz\]%29%24&input=paint%0Aplay%0Adevour%0Adevourr%0A) :)

Comment: @jensgram - I didn't know you could permalink regexpal until now! Never saw that link tucked in the corner like that :)

Comment: You should just beware that `[` and `]` are not escaped in the permalink and so must be escaped via a `\\` in SO links :)

Comment: Except that `y` is generally a vowel in English.  Also, Java’s `\W` works only on ASCII, not on Unicode.  The easiest way to try this stuff out is `perl -nle 'print if /pattern/' /usr/share/dict/words`.

Answer (score 0):

you need a regular expression like this

```
^.*[aeiou]([^aeiou]|nt)$
```

which zero or more chars, followed by one of a,e,i,o and u, followed by one char that isn't a vowel or by exactly nt

As was pointed out in the comments, the `[^aeiou]` doesn't perform as intended unless you assume only alpha chars are used

Comment: Your first regex will match `you8` or `bee#`

Comment: @M42: Duly noted, luckily I am only checking verbs that I know to be verbs and not have funky info like # and 8, but yeah it'd be cool to watch out for those anyhow (!)

Comment: I just assumed he is only dealing with alphabetic chars, but it is easily fixed as you have done in your answer. Nicely pointed out